# ElasticSearch- not returning proper value count

Tags: elasticsearch

The ES 1.4.2 Value Count aggregation is returning incorret values.
When I ran below query to get the total count of the array elements in the "durations" field, the value_count aggr is fetching the count of unique values.

Query:

```
{  
  "query": {  
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "sessions.applicationId": {
            "query": 208,
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "range": {
                "eventDate": {
                  "from": 1388916360000,
                  "to": 1389402273384,
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "Session_Count": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "durations"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result hits

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "users",
    "_type": "sessions",
    "_id": "18967_20140105_CF538C86DEBC432DBDE40887FE6CA051",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "eventDate": "2014-01-05T17:01:18",
      "manufacturer": "apple",
      "applicationId": "208",
      "durations": [
        2,
        2
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "users",
    "_type": "sessions",
    "_id": "2386_20140109_5AC476D2FC784826A3B3A6584578597E",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "eventDate": "2014-01-09T15:55:53",
      "manufacturer": "apple",
      "applicationId": "208",
      "durations": [
        1,
        1
      ]
    } 
]

"aggregations": {
  "Session_Count": {
    "value": 2
  }
}
```

In the above result of the value_count of "durations" arrays [2,2] and [1,1] is coming as 2. I was expecting it as 4 as given in the ES reference documentation.
The values are coming correctly for distinct values like for durations [1,2],[3],[3,2,4] it is 6.

Is it an issue with the Elastic Search Value_count functioanlity or Am I missing something here.
Can anyone please let me know on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

value_count provides you with the number of unique values and not the total number of values.

For getting total number of values , you will need to use the following -

Declare durations as multi field and add a field called totalTokens with type token_count. 
LINK - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#token_count

What happens here is that , an addition field called durations.totalTokens would be created per document that has the number of tokens for that field.
Now apply sum aggregation of that field to get the right answer.

```
{  
  "query": {  
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "sessions.applicationId": {
            "query": 208,
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "range": {
                "eventDate": {
                  "from": 1388916360000,
                  "to": 1389402273384,
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "Session_Count": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "duration.totalTokens"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I can get conditional partial count. Finding the number of Sessions with duration > 5

Comment: As i feel its a different question from the current one and as this should be a question by itself , can you please paste it as a different question ?

Comment: Have the New Question created 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922350/elastic-search-range-aggregation-on-array-field

Answer (score 0):

Just to be specific here, aggregations always return the count of the individual buckets. That is why it is returning the count of the individual durations and not the complete result.